# How to make this change of variables?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

"Show that if we introduce the independent variable $x = \sqrt{\frac{z}{L}}$ then the equation $zZ''(z) + Z'(z) + v^2Z(z)=0$ becomes $Z''(x) + \frac{1}{x} Z'(x) +4v^2LZ(x)=0$ for $0<x<1$.

So what I tried to do was differentiate $Z(x)$ w.r.t $z$. I got:

$(Z(x))' = Z'(x)\frac{\sqrt{\frac{z}{L}}}{2z}$

$(Z(x))'' = \frac{1}{2z}(\sqrt{\frac{z}{L}}Z''(x) +\frac{\sqrt{\frac{z}{L}}}{2z}Z'(x))$

But when I put these into the equation (and doing some rearranging) I get to

$\sqrt{\frac{z}{L}}Z''(x) + \frac{2\sqrt{\frac{z}{L}}}{z}Z'(x) + 2v^2Z(x) = 0$ which I don't think can be rearranged to give the right answer. Have I used the right method? And can you see where I have gone wrong in my calculations if so? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your transformation is $x=\sqrt{\frac{z}{L}}$ or $z=Lx^{2}$. Thus $dz=2Lxdx$. Then

$$ \frac{dZ}{dz} = \frac{dZ}{2Lxdx}=\frac{1}{2Lx}\frac{dZ}{dx}  $$ and
$$ \frac{d^{2}Z}{dz^{2}}=\frac{d}{dz}\frac{dZ}{dz}=\frac{d}{2Lxdx}\frac{dZ}{2Lxdx}=\frac{1}{4L^{2}x^{2}}\frac{d^{2}Z}{dx^{2}}. $$ So, plug all these into the original equation to get:

$$ Z''(x)+\frac{2}{x} Z'(x)+4Lv^{2}Z(x)=0. $$ Therefore I get what you publish with the exception of the 2 in the second term. Would you double check your problem statement?

Cheers,

Paul Safier

Comment: Thanks for your help Paul. I think the $\frac{d^2Z}{dz^2}$ should however be :

$\frac{d^2Z}{dz^2} = \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{2Lx} \frac{dZ}{dx})*\frac{dx}{dz}$
$=\frac{1}{4L^2x^2}Z''(x) - \frac{1}{4L^2x^3}Z'(x)$

Which after substitution gives the desired answer. Thank you for giving me the method though. Helped a lot.