# Change of Variables in differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the equation $zZ''(z) + Z'(z) + \alpha^2Z(z) = 0$ use the change of variables $x = \sqrt{\frac{z}{a}}$ where $a$ is a constant to map the problem to the differential equation $Z''(x) + \frac{1}{x}Z'(x) + \gamma^2 Z(x) = 0,$ where $\gamma = 2\alpha \sqrt{a}$

Attempt:
I think I am struggling to get the chain rule correct for this particular case. Here is my attempt:  $$\frac{d}{dz} = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{dx}{dz} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{za}}\frac{d}{dx} = \frac{1}{2xa} \frac{d}{dx}$$ This means by a similar argument $$\frac{d^2}{dz^2} = \frac{1}{4x^2a^2}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$$

I am not really sure where to go from here.

Thanks.

Comment: This is essentially the same question as here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582319/how-to-make-this-change-of-variables/582511#582511

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ \frac{dZ}{dz} = \frac{dZ}{dx}\frac{dx}{dz}=\frac{dZ}{dx}\frac{1}{2ax}$$
$$ \frac{d^{2}Z}{dz^{2}}=\frac{d}{dz}[\frac{dZ}{dx}\frac{1}{2ax}], $$
but $dz=2axdx$, so
$$ \frac{d}{dz}[\frac{dZ}{dx}\frac{1}{2ax}] = \frac{1}{2ax}\frac{d}{dx}[\frac{dZ}{dx}\frac{1}{2ax}] = \frac{1}{4a^{2}x^{2}} \frac{d^{2}Z}{dx^{2}} -\frac{1}{4a^{2}x^{3}} \frac{dZ}{dx}. $$
Now 
$$ z\frac{d^{2}Z}{dz^{2}} + \frac{dZ}{dz} + \alpha^{2}Z =0$$ becomes
$$ \frac{d^{2}Z}{dx^{2}} + \frac{1}{x}\frac{dZ}{dx} + 4a\alpha^{2}Z=0. $$

Cheers,

Paul Safier

Comment: Thanks, I see that this gives the result, however, I have two questions, which underly the reasons for me having dificulty with this.  In the first line, if we put in the actual $z$ dependence, then we obtain $$\frac{dZ(z)}{dz} = \frac{dZ(z)}{dx}\frac{dx}{dz}.$$ But it seems to me, that $d Z(z)/dx$ has been interpreted as $ d Z(x)/dx$ Could you clarify why?

Comment: Also, in the final part, $Z(z)$ has been simply replaced by $Z(x)$ Why can this be done?  Thanks very much.

Comment: Transforming the equation from one where z is the independant variable to one where x is the independant variable is saying that now $Z=Z(x)$ instead of $Z=Z(z)$.

Comment: Thanks.  I am now trying to implement this change of variable in Maple.  I have the eqn for $Z$ in terms of $Z(z)$.  Can you clarify how I would do this?  I was trying the following code, but it did not return anything: with[PDEtools] <newline> PDE :=.... <newline> tr:={z=x^2a} <newline> dchange(tr, PDE} Thanks. Edit: I will put this in another thread.

Comment: I don't use Maple.

Comment: No problem, I thought about this and have already put it in another thread.  Thanks for your time.